# getting error while uploading on server

Tags: php, opencart

I am developing opencart application , i installed in on localhost ,and customize it but now i am trying to upload it to server but it get error

> Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: http:// wrapper is
>   disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   /home/content/29/9716229/html/johndhan/telhemboradz/index.php on line
>   17
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(http://249development.us/johndhan/telhemboradz/system/startup.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper
>   could be found in
>   /home/content/29/9716229/html/johndhan/telhemboradz/index.php on line
>   17
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   'http://249development.us/johndhan/telhemboradz/system/startup.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/29/9716229/html/johndhan/telhemboradz/index.php on line
>   17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use paths for your files not HTTP url's. Open your `config.php` file and `admin/config.php` file and change

```
http://249development.us/
```

to

```
/home/content/29/9716229/html/
```

for all of the paths except for those that start `HTTP_` or `HTTPS_` in the define's

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to include a remote file via HTTP. If this is intentionally the case, then you need to enable the http:// wrapper - as suggested by the warning you are getting. If this is not the case, then consider removing the URL `http://249development.us/` from the `require_once` statements.